# OAuth 1.0 Signature Calculation for E*TRADE API

Tags: oauth, signature, etrade-api

The E*TRADE Developer Platform uses the OAuth authorization protocol, version 1.0a. The e*Trade developers guides (https://developer.etrade.com/getting-started/developer-guides) contains the following example:

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Key | c5bb4dcb7bd6826c7c4340df3f791188 |
| Secret | 7d30246211192cda43ede3abd9b393b9 |
| Access Token | VbiNYl63EejjlKdQM6FeENzcnrLACrZ2JYD6NQROfVI= |
| Access Secret | XCF9RzyQr4UEPloA+WlC06BnTfYC1P0Fwr3GUw/B0Es= |
| Timestamp | 1344885636 |
| Nonce | 0bba225a40d1bbac2430aa0c6163ce44 |
| HTTP Method | GET |
| URL | https://api.etrade.com/v1/accounts/list |

The expected signature is: **UOnPVdzExTAgHkcGWLLfeTaaMSM%3D**

This is the signature string and key I have built:

| field | value |
| --- | --- |
| base string | GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.etrade.com%2Fv1%2Faccounts%2Flist&oauth_consumer_key%3Dc5bb4dcb7bd6826c7c4340df3f791188%26oauth_nonce%3D0bba225a40d1bbac2430aa0c6163ce44%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1344885636%26oauth_token%3DVbiNYl63EejjlKdQM6FeENzcnrLACrZ2JYD6NQROfVI%3D |
| Key | 7d30246211192cda43ede3abd9b393b9&XCF9RzyQr4UEPloA+WlC06BnTfYC1P0Fwr3GUw/B0Es= |

But my resulting Signature is: **8alOEOXdzxx+N7+77VRyducKWJM=**, which is different than the expected value. What am I doing wrong?

To hash the base string I call (this is a DELPHI class for HMAC_SHA1 hash)

```
result := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(THashSHA1.GetHMACAsBytes(AData, AKey));
```

I believe that this hash is correct as it returns the correct signature  for another OAuth signature example (as shown below) at ttps://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#sig_base_example where they provided the base string and key.

| field | value |
| --- | --- |
| base string | GET&http%3A%2F%2Fphotos.example.net%2Fphotos&file%3Dvacation.jpg%26oauth_consumer_key%3Ddpf43f3p2l4k3l03%26oauth_nonce%3Dkllo9940pd9333jh%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1191242096%26oauth_token%3Dnnch734d00sl2jdk%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26size%3Doriginal |
| key | kd94hf93k423kf44&pfkkdhi9sl3r4s00 |
| signature | tR3+Ty81lMeYAr/Fid0kMTYa/WM= |

I think I just missing some little detail in the base string and possibly the key.

```
// ETrade test case from https://developer.etrade.com/getting-started/developer-guides
// Following the Signture example
//    Item          Value
//    Key   c         5bb4dcb7bd6826c7c4340df3f791188
//    Secret          7d30246211192cda43ede3abd9b393b9
//    Access Token  VbiNYl63EejjlKdQM6FeENzcnrLACrZ2JYD6NQROfVI=
//    Access Secret XCF9RzyQr4UEPloA+WlC06BnTfYC1P0Fwr3GUw/B0Es=
//    Timestamp     1344885636
//    Nonce         0bba225a40d1bbac2430aa0c6163ce44
//    HTTP Method     GET
//    URL             https://api.etrade.com/v1/accounts/list
//    Resulting signature   UOnPVdzExTAgHkcGWLLfeTaaMSM%3D

URL := URIEncode('https://api.etrade.com/v1/accounts/list');
URL := 'GET&' + URL + '&';
Data.Add('oauth_consumer_key=c5bb4dcb7bd6826c7c4340df3f791188');
Data.Add('&oauth_nonce=0bba225a40d1bbac2430aa0c6163ce44');
Data.Add('&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1');
Data.Add('&oauth_timestamp=1344885636');
Data.Add('&oauth_token=VbiNYl63EejjlKdQM6FeENzcnrLACrZ2JYD6NQROfVI=');
Data.Add('&oauth_version=1.0');
AData := Data[0];
for i:= 1 to Data.Count - 1 do
  AData := AData + Data[i];
AData := URL + URIEncode(AData);
AKey := '7d30246211192cda43ede3abd9b393b9&XCF9RzyQr4UEPloA+WlC06BnTfYC1P0Fwr3GUw/B0Es=';
result := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(THashSHA1.GetHMACAsBytes(AData, AKey));
// the incorrect result is returned

// an example from https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#sig_base_example
AString :=
  'GET&http%3A%2F%2Fphotos.example.net%2Fphotos&file%3Dvacation.jpg' +
  '%26oauth_consumer_key%3Ddpf43f3p2l4k3l03' +
  '%26oauth_nonce%3Dkllo9940pd9333jh' +
  '%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1' +
  '%26oauth_timestamp%3D1191242096' +
  '%26oauth_token%3Dnnch734d00sl2jdk' +
  '%26oauth_version%3D1.0' +
  '%26size%3Doriginal';
result := EncodeBase64(THashSHA1.GetHMACAsBytes(AString,
                      'kd94hf93k423kf44&pfkkdhi9sl3r4s00'));
// returns the correct hash
```

Comment: what delphi version do you use?

Comment: I am using 10.4.2 community edition, but just got 11.2.   I am using  Rest.Authenticor.OAuth and Rest.Client for an example of how to do it.  The Delphi implementation does not appear to match what Etrade expects.  The SHA1 hash algorithm is in System.Hash and I believe it is correct.

I compared the Oauth code between 10.4.2 and 11.2 and there are no differences.  I had hoped to find a bug fix.

Comment: I don't understand the table. Can you show your code including the constants comprising the table? And did you imply that you have a sample that is working?  When you URLEncode the string, it should convert the & for you.

Comment: The example from https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#anchor13  works


    AString :=
      'GET&http%3A%2F%2Fphotos.example.net%2Fphotos&file%3Dvacation.jpg' +
      '%26oauth_consumer_key%3Ddpf43f3p2l4k3l03' +
      '%26oauth_nonce%3Dkllo9940pd9333jh' +
      '%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1' +
      '%26oauth_timestamp%3D1191242096' +
      '%26oauth_token%3Dnnch734d00sl2jdk' +
      '%26oauth_version%3D1.0' +
      '%26size%3Doriginal';
    result := EncodeBase64(THashSHA1.GetHMACAsBytes(AString,
                          'kd94hf93k423kf44&pfkkdhi9sl3r4s00'));

Comment: Please leave this open as I very much want to know what I am missing in my base string or in the key information passed to the HMAC-SHA1 encoder.  But I did find a work around using a 3rd party library Chilkat API at https://www.chilkatsoft.com/

Answer (score 1):

One thing obviously wrong in your code is the key. It should be the consumer secret and access secret concatenated with an "&". But each of them should be URL encoded first.
The good news is that I can get a matching signature given by the etrade developer guides (https://developer.etrade.com/getting-started/developer-guides). The bad news is that this may be wrong according to the oauth spec (https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/).

Here is the key and message to be encoded:

```
String access_token ="VbiNYl63EejjlKdQM6FeENzcnrLACrZ2JYD6NQROfVI=";
String oauth_nonce="0bba225a40d1bbac2430aa0c6163ce44";
String consumer_key="c5bb4dcb7bd6826c7c4340df3f791188";
String consumer_secret="7d30246211192cda43ede3abd9b393b9";
String access_secret="XCF9RzyQr4UEPloA+WlC06BnTfYC1P0Fwr3GUw/B0Es=";
String key = URLEncoder.encode(consumer_secret, "UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode(access_secret, "UTF-8");

String msg = 
    "GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.etrade.com%2Fv1%2Faccounts%2Flist" + "&" +
    "oauth_consumer_key" + "%3D" + consumer_key + "%26" +
    "oauth_nonce" + "%3D" + oauth_nonce + "%26" +
    "oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26" +
    "oauth_timestamp%3D1344885636%26" + 
    "oauth_token" + "%3D" + URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.encode(access_token, "UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
```

As you can see that the token is URL encoded twice. The oauth_version is missing from the parameter list. According to the oauth v1 spec, it should be there. But this seems to be the only way to get a matching signature.

For everyone's convenience, here is a complete listing of a Java program to show the calculations.

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Oauth1Signature {
    private static final String HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA1";
    //private static final String ENC = "UTF-8";

    private static String access_token ="VbiNYl63EejjlKdQM6FeENzcnrLACrZ2JYD6NQROfVI=";
    private static String access_secret="XCF9RzyQr4UEPloA+WlC06BnTfYC1P0Fwr3GUw/B0Es=";
    private static String oauth_nonce="0bba225a40d1bbac2430aa0c6163ce44";
    
    private static String consumer_key="c5bb4dcb7bd6826c7c4340df3f791188";
    private static String consumer_secret="7d30246211192cda43ede3abd9b393b9";

    public static String hmacSha1Base64(String data, String key)
            throws SignatureException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException    {
        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
        mac.init(signingKey);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((mac.doFinal(data.getBytes())));
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String hmac;
        
        // example from https://developer.etrade.com/getting-started/developer-guides
        // Expected signature: UOnPVdzExTAgHkcGWLLfeTaaMSM=
        // Note: can get this signature only if oauth_version is not included in the msg to be hashed and 
        //       token encoded twice, contradicting oauth 1.0 spec
        String key = URLEncoder.encode(consumer_secret, "UTF-8") + "&" + URLEncoder.encode(access_secret, "UTF-8");

        String msg = 
            "GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.etrade.com%2Fv1%2Faccounts%2Flist" + "&" +
            "oauth_consumer_key" + "%3D" + consumer_key + "%26" +
            "oauth_nonce" + "%3D" + oauth_nonce + "%26" +
            "oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26" +
            "oauth_timestamp%3D1344885636%26" + 
            "oauth_token" + "%3D" + URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.encode(access_token, "UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
            // + "%26" + "oauth_version" + "%3D" + "1.0";

        hmac = hmacSha1Base64(msg, key);
        System.out.println("msg=" + msg);
        System.out.println("key=" + key);
        System.out.println(hmac);
        //output: UOnPVdzExTAgHkcGWLLfeTaaMSM=

        //example from https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#anchor46
        // working as expected
        String key2 = "kd94hf93k423kf44&pfkkdhi9sl3r4s00";
        String msg2 = 
            "GET&http%3A%2F%2Fphotos.example.net%2Fphotos" + "&" + 
            "file%3Dvacation.jpg" + "%26" +
            "oauth_consumer_key%3Ddpf43f3p2l4k3l03" + "%26" + 
            "oauth_nonce%3Dkllo9940pd9333jh" + "%26" + 
            "oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1" + "%26" +
            "oauth_timestamp%3D1191242096" + "%26" +
            "oauth_token%3Dnnch734d00sl2jdk" + "%26" +
            "oauth_version%3D1.0" + "%26" +
            "size%3Doriginal";
        
        hmac = hmacSha1Base64(msg2, key2);
        System.out.println("msg2=" + msg2);
        System.out.println("key2=" + key2);
        System.out.println(hmac);
        // match expected result: tR3+Ty81lMeYAr/Fid0kMTYa/WM=
    }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering about the keys being URIEncoded and if they should be encoded twice.  And I have also tried with and without the OAuth version.  Thank you for your reply.  I will give this a try.

Also on the Chilkat library.  I got through step one of the authorization, but I can't get step two to work.  Crossing my fingers I can just do it all directly.

Comment: I followed your example exactly and I get a match.

GET&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.etrade.com%2Fv1%2Faccounts%2Flist&oauth_consumer_key%3Dc5bb4dcb7bd6826c7c4340df3f791188%26oauth_nonce%3D0bba225a40d1bbac2430aa0c6163ce44%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1344885636%26oauth_token%3DVbiNYl63EejjlKdQM6FeENzcnrLACrZ2JYD6NQROfVI%253D
7d30246211192cda43ede3abd9b393b9&XCF9RzyQr4UEPloA%2BWlC06BnTfYC1P0Fwr3GUw%2FB0Es%3D
Java Match: UOnPVdzExTAgHkcGWLLfeTaaMSM=

This is does not match what the Delphi OAuth1 classes do.

This question is answered.

Comment: @user5864258, if you think the question is answered, please help accept and vote up the answer as an acknowledgement of the answer and time spent on it.

Comment: It tells me I can't vote up the answer because I am too new.

The answer is exactly what I was looking for.  And I was able to apply it to create the proper header to get the call to https://apisb.etrade.com/oauth/request_token to work.

Comment: @user5864258, it sounds that this is what etrade implemented. Somehow they decided to drop the oauth_version and double encode the token... Glad to know it worked. Are you able to set the answer as accepted if you are not able to vote?

Comment: I don't see anyway to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the help I received I was able to create a class which correctly signs the headers for authorization and to get quotes

```
unit MyOauth;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Rest.Utils, DateUtils, System.Hash, System.NetEncoding,
  AuthSharedMem;

type
  TOathSignature = class(TObject)
  private
    FURL: string;
    FTimeStamp: string;
    FNonce: string;
    FToken: string;
    FCallback: string;
    FSignature: string;
    FConsumerKey: string;
    FConsumerSecret: string;
    FAccessSecret: string;
    FAction: string;
    FData: string;
    FKey: string;
    FRealm: string;
    FVerifier: string;
    FTokenSecret: string;

    function GetTimestamp: int64;
  public
    constructor Create(const AAction, AURL: string);

    function GetSignature(): string;
    function GetAuthorization: string;

    property Action: string read FAction write FAction;
    property AccessSecret: string read FAccessSecret write FAccessSecret;
    property Callback: string read FCallback write FCallback;
    property ConsumerKey: string read FConsumerKey write FConsumerKey;
    property ConsumerSecret: string read FConsumerSecret write FConsumerSecret;
    property URL: string read FURL write FURL;
    property Nonce: string read FNonce write FNonce;
    property Signature: string read FSignature write FSignature;
    property Timestamp: string read FTimeStamp write fTimestamp;
    property Token: string read FToken write FToken;
    property TokenSecret: string read FTokenSecret write FTokenSecret;
    property Data: string read FData;
    property Key: string read FKey;
    property Realm: string read FRealm write FRealm;
    property Verifier: string read FVerifier write FVerifier;
  end;


implementation

uses
  DebugMemory;

{ TOathSignature }

constructor TOathSignature.Create(const AAction, AURL: string);
begin
  Action := AAction;
  URL := AURL;
end;

function TOathSignature.GetSignature: string;
var
  URLEncoded: string;
  Data: TStringList;
  AData: string;
  AKey: string;
  i: integer;
  BaseURL: string;
  q: integer;
  Parameters: string;

begin
  if TimeStamp = '' then
    Timestamp := IntToStr(GetTimeStamp div 1000);
  if Nonce = '' then
    Nonce := THashMD5.GetHashString(TimeStamp + IntToStr(Random(MAXINT)));
  if ConsumerKey = '' then
    ConsumerKey := etrade_consumer_key;
  if ConsumerSecret = '' then
    ConsumerSecret := etrade_consumer_secret;

  q := URL.IndexOf('?');
  if q < 0 then
  begin
    baseURL := URL;
    parameters := '';
  end
  else
  begin
    baseURL := URL.Substring(0, q);
    parameters := URL.Substring(q+1);
  end;
  URLEncoded := Action + '&' + URIEncode(BaseURL) + '&';
  Data := TStringList.Create('~', '&');
  try
    Data.StrictDelimiter := true;
    if parameters <> '' then
      Data.DelimitedText := parameters;
    if callback <> '' then
      Data.Add('oauth_callback=' + callback);
    Data.Add('oauth_consumer_key=' + ConsumerKey);
    Data.Add('oauth_nonce=' + Nonce);
    Data.Add('oauth_signature_method=' + 'HMAC-SHA1');
    Data.Add('oauth_timestamp=' + Timestamp);
    if Token <> '' then
      Data.Add('oauth_token=' + URIEncode(Token));
    if Verifier <> '' then
      Data.Add('oauth_verifier=' + Verifier);
    Data.Sort;
    AData := Data[0];
    for i:= 1 to Data.Count - 1 do
      AData := AData + '&' + Data[i];

    FData := URLEncoded + URIEncode(AData);

    FKey := URIEncode(ConsumerSecret) + '&';
    if AccessSecret <> '' then
      FKey := FKey + URIEncode(AccessSecret)
    else if TokenSecret <> '' then
      FKey := FKey + URIEncode(TokenSecret);
    signature := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(THashSHA1.GetHMACAsBytes(FData, FKey));
    result := signature;
    OutputDebugString(FData);
  finally
    data.Free;
  end;
end;

function TOathSignature.GetTimestamp: int64;
var
  epochStart: TDateTime;
  UDate: TDateTime;

begin
  epochStart := UnixDateDelta; // StrToDate('1/1/1970');
  UDate := TTimeZone.Local.ToUniversalTime(Now);
  result := round((UDate - epochStart) * 86400000.0);

  //OutputDebugString('%s %s', [IntToStr(DateTimeToUnix(UDate)), IntToStr(result div 1000)]);
end;

function TOathSignature.GetAuthorization: string;
var
  SignatureEncoded: string;
begin
  if Signature = '' then
    GetSignature;

  SignatureEncoded := URIEncode(Signature);

  if Callback = 'oob' then
    result := format('realm="",oauth_callback="oob",oauth_signature="%s",oauth_nonce="%s",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_consumer_key="%s",oauth_timestamp="%s"',
                     [SignatureEncoded, Nonce, URIEncode(Consumerkey), Timestamp])
  else if Verifier <> '' then
  begin
    result := format('realm="",' +
                     'oauth_signature="%s",' +
                     'oauth_nonce="%s",' +
                     'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",' +
                     'oauth_consumer_key="%s",' +
                     'oauth_timestamp="%s",' +
                     'oauth_verifier="%s",' +
                     'oauth_token="%s"',
            [SignatureEncoded, Nonce, UriEncode(ConsumerKey), Timestamp, Verifier, URIEncode(Token)]);
  end
  else
  begin
    result := format('oauth_signature="%s",' +
                     'oauth_nonce="%s",' +
                     'oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",' +
                     'oauth_consumer_key="%s",' +
                     'oauth_timestamp="%s",' +
                     'oauth_token="%s"',
            [SignatureEncoded, Nonce, UriEncode(ConsumerKey), Timestamp, URIEncode(Token)]);
  end;
  outputdebugstring(result);
end;

end.
```